# Deleting rows past a certain row index

Tags: sqlite

I have a table of `HighScores` which stores ditto; when the number of rows exceeds a certain count, I want the lowest scoring row to be removed. I've made  a trigger that successfully deals with the removal but now I can't make the row count check without running into an error.

Used Query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_lowest_score AFTER INSERT ON HighScoreTable
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM HighScoreTable WHERE score IN ( SELECT score FROM HighScoreTable ORDER BY score ASC LIMIT 1);
END;
```

I would like to clarify that while I may be inexperienced in SQL, I am determined to create my database with SQLite instead of any other (potentially easy) SQLs.

**NOTE:** The linked "duplicate" answer is not working as intended, I've tried modifying it but it seems flawed in its purpose.

**FINAL NOTE:** Seems the issue was that I tested with blank insertions. I retried with a defined insertion and it successfully puts that row in the correct order and removes the lowest score value. :^)

There seems to be however one kink in this Query; if I enter a score value that is the same as the lowest value & the table is at max limit, all rows matching the minimum score are deleted. This should not happen since the trigger starts deleting past the limit only.

Comment: So what is the error you are running to?

Comment: The mentioned Query runs fine, but all attempts i've made return an error in one way or another. For Example, I've used a "CASE WHEN Count(*)>50 THEN DELETE FROM HighScoreTable..." but it gives a syntax error. I've tried other variations but it's either syntax error or some other issue when I insert a record into the table.